# Showing a limit goes to zero

Tags: analysis, limits

Part of a proof I'm working on for Adv Calc/Real Analysis boils down to showing that 
$$\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \to 0 \text{ when } n \to \infty.$$

The only thing I can think of to rigorously show this using what we've learned is the limit definition, so formally: for all $\varepsilon > 0, \exists \hspace{2mm} n, m \hspace{2mm}s.t.\hspace{2mm} \text{for } n > m, \hspace{2mm} \big| \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \big| < \varepsilon \rightarrow \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} < \varepsilon $.

From here I would like to solve for $n$ as a function of epsilon, but I'm getting stuck. I thought of taking natural logs and getting:

$$ \log (n+1) + (n+1)\log2 < \log\varepsilon $$

But am not sure how to isolate $n$ from here.

Other ideas I have are to find something greater than $\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$ and show that's less than epsilon, or to split this fraction up in some meaningful way, but none of that has worked.

Does anyone have any useful hints? I feel like this should be a relatively straightforward problem, but maybe there's a trick I'm missing.

Comment: Hint: Look at the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^{n+1}$, up to the **third** term.  For small $\epsilon$, it gives a lousy bound for the $N_\epsilon$ beyond which the ratio is $\lt \epsilon$. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be that hard. For example: If $n>3$, then $2^n>n^2$, therefore:

$\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}<\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

From there on you can use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

for $n > 3 \Rightarrow 0<\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} < \dfrac{1}{n}\Rightarrow\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} = 0$